# What does it mean that you treat a weapon as a Martial Weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, weapons

[Halfling sling staffs](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/sling-staff-halfling) do 1d6/1d8 damage (small/medium). [Halfling rope-shot](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons/weapon-descriptions/halfling-rope-shot) do 1d4/1d6. In both of their descriptions (as well as in the [racial description for halflings](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/core-races/halfling#TOC-Standard-Racial-Traits)) it says that halfings treat these weapons as martial weapons. What does that mean?

I know martial weapons in general tend to be better than non-martial weapons, and do more damage, but how does this apply to these?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that you need Martial Weapon Proficiency, either from your class or from that feat, in order to wield them, just like any other martial weapon.  This is in contrast to their normal situation as exotic weapons, which means that no classes taken by a non-halfling can wield them by default and they always require a *specific* Exotic Weapon Proficiency to wield.